# How to find all dates between two dates and check if there is a "holiday"?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to find all the dates between two date columns and then check if there were holidays between those two dates for each row.
I have another table with all the holidays listed which I can join to.
If there is any holiday between the dates then put a yes flag for holiday.
What would be the best way to do it?
My database is Snowflake.

Table1

```
id   Country  Date1        Date2
1    DE       2018-12-23   2018-12-30
2    DE       2019-08-01   2019-08-09
...
3    DE       2019-04-28   2019-05-02
```

Table 2

```
Country  Date        Holiday
DE       2018-12-25  Christmas
DE       2019-05-01  Labor Day
```

I would like the result to look like

Result:

```
id  Country     Date1       Date2         is_holiday
1   DE          2018-12-23   2018-12-30   Yes
2   DE          2019-08-01   2019-08-09   No
...
3   DE          2019-04-28   2019-05-02   Yes
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) And first take a look at [mcve].

Comment: snowflake is schema name not database name

Comment: @jarlh I updated with more information

Comment: @saravanatn There is a data warehouse called Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a LEFT JOIN of the tables and group by:

```
select 
  t1.id, t1.Country, t1.date1, t1.date2,
  case count(t2.holiday) when 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end is_holiday 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1.country = t2.country and t2.date between t1.date1 and t1.date2
group by t1.id, t1.Country, t1.date1, t1.date2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7eTABe2rbxxn1gmwZHWCD3/0) (for MySQL but since I used standard SQL I believe it will work for Snowflake too).
Results:

```
| id  | Country | date1               | date2               | is_holiday |
| --- | ------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | ---------- |
| 1   | DE      | 2018-12-23 00:00:00 | 2018-12-30 00:00:00 | Yes        |
| 2   | DE      | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 2019-08-09 00:00:00 | No         |
| 3   | DE      | 2019-04-28 00:00:00 | 2019-05-02 00:00:00 | Yes        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Implying you have a [tally table](https://github.com/KuroxAraya/calendiarioSQL_CL/blob/master/calendarioCL.sql) (it's on TSQL but you can work with something similar) with every day and holiday within a range then :

```
SELECT E.*, 
    TOTAL_DAYS = (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(INT,holiday,112)) AS D FROM CALENDAR C WHERE holiday = 0 AND C.dateValue BETWEEN begDATE AND endDATE)
FROM yourTable E
```

Answer (score 0):

With a table Table_DateFromTo:
[image]
And table Table_HolidayDates: 
[image]
You can run a query like this:

```
    SELECT DateFrom as MinDate,
        DateTo as MaxDate,
      (SELECT  count(*)
        FROM    Table_HolidayDates
        WHERE   Date >= A.DateFrom
        AND     Date < A.DateTo) as HolidayCount
  FROM Table_DateFromTo A
```

It gives you following output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could find the `DISTINCT COUNT` of the holidays for the given dates and subtract it from the actual day difference. The following query should do what you want:,

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE)
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES
('2018-12-23','2018-12-30'),
('2019-04-28','2019-05-02')
CREATE TABLE #table2 (Country VARCHAR(2), [Date] DATE, Holiday VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES
('DE','2018-12-25','Christmas'),
('DE','2019-05-01','Labor Day'),
('DE','2019-04-29','SoMe Holiday1')


SELECT Date1,Date2,DATEDIFF(DAY,Date1,Date2)-T.holidays [Days (Excl Holidays)], T.holidays AS [Number_of_Holidays]
FROM #table1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Holiday) FROM #table2 WHERE[Date] BETWEEN Date1 and Date2) ) ) AS T(Holidays)
```

The result is as below,

```
Date1       Date2       Days (Excl Holidays)  Number_of_Holidays
2018-12-23  2018-12-30  6                     1
2019-04-28  2019-05-02  2                     2
```

Comment: I don't think there is cross apply in Snowflake.  I updated the post.

Comment: You can use a correlated query to implement the same logic